# Eclipse: Why is my JRE System Library not appearing when I create a new Java Project?

Tags: java, eclipse

> Just got a new laptop- every time I have to manually go to project -> build path -> add libraries to add the JRE System Library. If I don’t then I get an error “The type Java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I tried restarting eclipse and following steps from other posts but the problem still remains. It wasn’t like this on my old pc, so is anyone experiencing the same issue or knows how to fix it?

Comment: Which Java do you use with which Eclipse? What do you have configured in the preferences _Java > Installed JRE_? Does the _Problems_ view show errors and if yes, what are the error messages?